# Evaluate prediction with a binary vector in python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to take two vectors (prediction, actual) and have a simple evaluation of the prediction in Python: (both vectors are ndarrays)

```
prediction = [ 1 1 1 0 0 1 ]
actual     = [ 1 0 1 0 1 0 ]

score = 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 / 6 = 3/6 = 50%
```

I tried `&&` operators and `numpy.mul` ... there was always some transformation to do. I would appreciate something very simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> prediction = np.array([1,1,1,0,0,1])
>>> actual     = np.array([1,0,1,0,1,0])
>>> np.sum(prediction == actual, dtype=float) / len(prediction)
0.5
>>> np.mean(prediction == actual)
0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
score = 100.0 * sum(1 for x,y in itertools.izip(prediction, actual) if x == y) / len(actual)
```

Output:

```
50.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`sum([prediction[i]==actual[i] for i in range(len(prediction))])/len(prediction)`

Comment: When prediction and actual are 0, `prediction*actual` will be 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this using standard python operators:

```
>>> prediction = [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 ];
>>> actual     = [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 ];
>>> 100.0 * sum([not p ^ a for p, a in zip(prediction, actual)])/len(prediction)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
predicted = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
actual    = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
assert len(predicted) == len(actual)
score = sum(map(lambda x: 1. if x[0] == x[1] else 0., zip(predicted, actual))) / len(predicted)
print(score) # <0,1> where 0=complete mismatch and 1=complete match
```